# Java - How To Compare Elements In An Object List

Tags: java, object

I am trying to get and compare average scores of a `Player` object stored in a `List`, where every object has a `first name`, `last name`, and a list of `scores`. An example of this would be (`List` with one object):

`[0] Firstname: "Michael", Lastname: "Morris", Scores: [88, 92]`

I have code with a nested for loop within a for loop that gives me an `OutOfBounds` error. I need to get the average of scores per `Player` and return the highest `Player` with the highest average. Here's what I have at the moment (The naming is kind off):

```
public static PlayerScores findHighestScorer(List<PlayerScores> players) {
    String team = players.toString();

PlayerScores thePlayers = new PlayerScores("", ""); // What to return
for (int i = 0; i < team.length() - 1; ++i) { // Get every player and their average score
    PlayerScores player = players.get(i); // First player
    int avg = player.getAverage();
    for (int j = i + 1; j < team.length(); ++j) {
        PlayerScores player2 = players.get(j); // FIXME: OutOfBoundsException Error
        int avg2 = player2.getAverage();
        if (avg2 < avg) {
            thePlayers = player;
        } else if (avg2 > avg) {
            thePlayers = player2;
        } else {
            thePlayers = player;
        }
    }
}

return thePlayers;
```

Any and all suggestions would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Why are you checking bounds of teams array in the second loop when you are fetching from players?

Comment: because I don't have anything to use as a length other than the team string

Comment: You need to post this data structure because your trouble traversing it is hard to diagnose otherwise. Seems like you could use the length of players list to get a player.

Comment: I got the code to work after changing "team.length()" to "players.size()," letting me delete the team string

Comment: I strongly suggest you visit oracle documentation on all the accessible properties of an object implementing list interface. Or anything else java related for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem! Cheers.

```
public static PlayerScores findHighestScorer(List<PlayerScores> players) {
    PlayerScores bestScore = null;

    // loop through list...
    for (PlayerScores score : players) {
        if (bestScore == null) {
            bestScore = score;
        } else {
            if (bestScore.getAverage() < score.getAverage()) {
                bestScore = score;
            }
        }
    }

    return bestScore;
}
```